# Problema con evento onclick de un boton en asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Estoy haciendo una tabla **dinámica** en *ASP*. Dicha tabla lleva botones en una de las celdas.

Tengo el siguiente código en el `page_load`:

```
StringBuilder htmlStr = new StringBuilder();
htmlStr.Append(
 "<asp:button onclick='bttn_pdf_Click' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' ID='Bttn_PDF'>PDF</asp:button>"
);
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlStr.ToString() });
```

Esto solo es la parte de los botones que es donde tengo problemas, la idea es que al darle click se descargue un *PDF*, pero el problema es que al darle click muestra el siguiente error en consola:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bttn_pdf_Click is not defined
 at HTMLUnknownElement.onclick (VM184 panel.aspx:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

En el código que muestras, estás intentando ejecutar la función en el lado del cliente (en el navegador) y necesitarás javascript. En este caso:

1. Lo normal es que el handler del evento onclick sea una función y te faltan los paréntesis. Por tanto el código debería ser `onclick="bttn_pdf_Click()`
2. Tendrás que crear en javascript la funcion bttn_pdf_Click() de la forma:

   ```
   function bttn_pdf_Click(){
     //Código que realice la llamada al servidor para generar el PDF
   }
   ```

Quizás te convendría más que el button ejecutara directamente la llamada en servidor. En este caso deberías poner `onserverclick="bttn_pdf_Click"` (y por supuesto tendrás que tener declarada esta función en tu código asp). Puedes ver la documentación de eventos en click en servidor aquí: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.serverclick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar elementos dinámicamente a la interfaz, es preferible crear un método que inserte el elemento en el documento:

```
public void AgregarBoton()
{
    Button nuevo_boton = new Button();
    nuevo_boton.ID = "Bttn_PDF";
    nuevo_boton.Text = "PDF";
    nuevo_boton.Click += new EventHandler(bttn_pdf_Click);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(nuevo_boton);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Según tu ejemplo y el de W3 a tu código HTML le faltan los paréntesis:

```
onclick='bttn_pdf_Click'
```

debería ser:

```
onclick='bttn_pdf_Click()'
```

y Debe Existir el método javascript:

```
function bttn_pdf_Click(){
  //Código que realice la llamada al servidor para generar el PDF
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp